# Настройка соединения с ноутбука к компьютеру

Tags: сеть

Есть ноутбук lenovo (лоу модель) и рабочая машина, подключенная через кабельное в сеть(сетевая встроенная). Задача сделать интернет на ноуте с минимальными затратами и без подключения второго айпи. Желательно развернутей обьяснить, если не жалко.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С минимальными затратами, но как следствие наименее удобный вариант - тот, который я описал выше! Потребуется приобрести, PCI сетевую карту, патч-корд, кроссовер (можно обжать самому, если не умеете, купите, также может подойти и не кроссовер, но тут всё зависит от сетевух, поэтому лучше перестрахуйтесь и купите кроссовер). Втыкаете сетевуху в свободный порт на компе, ставите драйвера для неё, посредством патч-корда соединяете вторую сетевуху с ноутом. На компе заходите в Панель управления - сетевые подключения и щёлкаете правой кнопкой мыши по подключению с ноутом, выбираете пункт свойства - Вкладка "дополнительно", ставите галочку "Разрешить другим пользователям сети использовать подключение к интернету данного компьютера".

Тоже самое можно провернуть и купив wi-fi карточку в комп, тогда избавитесь от провода между компом и ноутом. Цена вопроса: сетевая-150-200 руб, патч-корд - 50 руб.

P.S.Если живёте в Питере, могу отдать всё необходимое за символическую бутылку пива. ))

**Добавление.**

Да в принципе настройка не отличается от описанного, единственное, что вместо сетевой у вас wi-fi карточка, ну и в свойствах обоих адаптеров зайдите на вкладку "беспроводные сети", там жмёте "добавить" и заполняете:

- SSID-произвольное название (имя вашей сети).
- Снимаете галочку "Ключ предоставлен автоматически" и вписываете ключ (надо придумать самому,д лина зависит от типа шифрования,при WEP 5 или 13 знаков).
- Ставите галочку "Это прямое соединение компьютер-компьютер; точки доступа не используются".
- На вкладке подключение ставите галку "Подключаться, если сеть находится в радиусе действия".

Эти настройки необходимо произвести как на компе, так и на ноуте! Вроде всё, надеюсь ничего не забыл! А адаптеры WI-FI, по крайней мере у нас, стоят 450 руб и выше.

Comment: Жаль, что не в Питере (( Но Большое спасибо) Просто и понятно.) А вот как тока спрашивать на рынке патч код кроссовер) Они мну поймут?? (не все же граммотные)

Comment: если на рынке,то точно поймут,если что скажите,что это перекрёстный патч-корд)Будут проблемы пишите)Всегда рад помочь))

Comment: Еще раз спасибо) Попробую такой вариант.
Отпишусь.

Comment: Ситуация изменилась малость. Как говорится аппетиты у людей растут.(ноут то не мой). Теперь интересует вопрос насчет wi-fi карточки и можно ли уложиться в районе 100-150 грн\280-450 рублей? если да то тогда про настройку тоже плз...

Comment: Кажется модераторам пора закрывать тему. Это для другого форума. Можно даже не обсуждать, и  воспользоваться поиском по предложенным выше вариантам. А соревноваться в дешевизне и сложности подключения можно бесконечно.

Comment: А зачем удалили последний пост.) Верните плз, там о настройках, а можно и закрыть тему.

Answer (score 3):

Если нет желания слушать шум включенного компьютера и есть желание пользоваться ноутом свободно (если у него есть встроенный wi-fi), то поставьте маршрутизатор (роутер), можно D-link DIR-320, описание [здесь](http://dlink.ru/ru/products/2/786.html). Цена вопроса - около полутора т.р. Альтернативные прошивки и советы - [здесь](http://asusforum.ru).  Плюсы - отсутствие шума, экономия электроэнергии, беспроводной инет. Минусы - не умеет варить кофе.

Comment: Полностью согласен насчет роутера.

Comment: Спасибо, Но слышал такой вариант. проблема как раз что дешевле было.

Answer (score 0):

Покупаете вторую сетевуху или Wi-fi модуль в комп и раздаёте нет на ноут). Более подробно напишу, если обозначите, что за операционка стоит на компе. ) Инет на ноуте само собой будет работать, пока комп включен. )

Comment: На компе ХР СП3 ВЛ. На ноуте тоже самое, тока не ВЛ а чья-то кривая сборка...

Answer (score 0):

> кабельное

Если речь про интернет через кабельный модем (типа Ariss от Tvoe.TV), то у модема два разъема - USB и ethernet. И если не требуется лазить с ноутбука на стационар и обратно, то можно подключить к модему оба устройства.

Если брать роутер - обратить внимание, что если есть привязка к MAC оборудования, то возможно понадобится на WAN (инетовский разъем роутера) склонировать MAC-адрес компьютера (или модема).

PS: D-link не рекомендую - дешевая и не всегда качественная китайская продукция.

PPS: Лучше более конкретно описать, что за оборудование используется, как оно подключено и какова политика провайдера :-)

Comment: D-Link или нет - дело вкуса, здесь надо посоветовать человеку максимально бюджетно-беспроблемное решение. Dir-320 рекомендую по собственному опыту. Не буду рекламировать, но наличие usb wi-fi и альтернативных прошивок - хороший плюс. Что такое Ariss - знаю, но любой роутер соединяет компьютеры в сеть, так что зайти с одного на другой проблем  не представляет. МАС-адрес клонировать можно, но, кажется, провайдеры перестали уже этим баловаться (в смысле привязывать).

Comment: >МАС-адрес клонировать можно, но, кажется, провайдеры перестали уже этим баловаться (в смысле привязывать).

твое.тв балуется. Корбина (билайн) с домашними сетями - тоже.

>но любой роутер соединяет компьютеры

спасибо, я в курсе.

Comment: Ноут lenovo g555....

Комп.а точнее - материнка As Rock 770DE+
познания в сети не очень(( А наш провайдер гордо утаивает политику насчет МАС адресса но по слухам тоже не превязывают
www.matrixhome.net

Comment: http://www.matrixhome.net/offer/
<i>4.3.5. В случае смены своего MAC адреса сообщить об этом Провайдеру в целях регистрации данных изменений.</i>
Это "стандартная" "домашняя сеть". Т.е. в квартиру заходит ethernet-провод, который подключается к ПК.

Comment: замечу - платно..а цель  была -с минимальными затратами

Comment: с минимальными затратами:<p>
- клонируете MAC на ноутбук (под win - в свойствах драйвера сетевого адаптера)<p>
- переписываете все сетевые настройки с настольника на ноут (IP, DNS или если все автоматом - выставляете автомат).<p>
- подключаете к шнурку<p>
Как только понадобится интернет на настольнике - перетыкаете шнур.
Устраивает?
Затраты составляют 0 руб. и от 15 минут до 1 часа личного времени на первоначальную настройку.

Comment: логично)

а с одного канала\ip значит никак?

Comment: без покупки дополнительных аппаратных средств (будь-то дополнительная сетевая карта, роутер или пр.) - не-а.

Comment: ну допустим.
я знаю что без них никак.Но. слышал что по дешевле есть чем роутер за 1.500 руб\350-400грн

Comment: Другой вариант - сетевуха в комп вторая. ~100-500 рублей.
+ патч-корд (сетевой шнур). Можно кроссовый (с перевернутыми пара, для подключения компов напрямую), можно обычный (обычный, 1-к-1, для подключения ПК к свитчу). Все равно сейчас ВСЕ современные сетевухи умеют "переворачивать" кабель.

Comment: а если насчет wi-fi карточки и можно ли уложиться в районе 100-150 грн\280-450 рублей? если да то тогда про настройку тоже плз...

Comment: только если б/у покупать.
Новая - от 500 руб.
Обратить внимание, чтобы карточка умела режим ad-hoc. Это как раз режим, когда она умеет подцепляться к другой wi-fi-карточке. Иначе нужна wifi точка доступа. А она стоит существенно дороже.